# Are the following phase portraits drawn (well, at least sketched) correctly, in terms of their behaviour?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have a linear system: 
$\frac{dx}{dt}=ax+y; \frac{dy}{dt}=-x+ay$.

I'm trying to investigate pictorially what happens for $a$ negative, $0$  and positive.
Now, I know that the eigenvalues I eventually get are: $\lambda=a\pm i$  for $a \neq0$; $\lambda=\pm i$  for $a=0$.

Here are my sketches. My question is: are the following sketches accurate (in terms of the nature of the respective critical points) and is the behaviour of the system indicated correctly?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Eigenvectors, please.

Comment: $v_1=(i,1)^T, v_2=(-i,1)^T$.

Comment: Brill. Thanks. Yes, I can see from the solutions how this is the case. A general question: how can I determine the directions of the arrows on the phase portraits? Obviously, if it's an unstable spiral, the arrows point outwards, but what about for nodes (stable and unstable)? Is there an easy way to determine in what directions the arrows ought to be pointing (for certain areas of the portrait)?

Comment: @Amzoti: What do $\frac{dy}{dt}$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}$ mean, though, graphically? Because, obviously, we can't always visualise how $t$ changes with $y$ and $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the system:

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=ax+y \\
\dfrac{dy}{dt}=-x+ay$$

We can find the [*Jacobian*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) matrix as:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}a & 1\\-1 & a\end{bmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues of the this matrix are given by:

$$|A - \lambda I | = 0 \implies \lambda_{1,2} = a ~ \pm ~ i$$

- For $a \lt 0$, we get a stable spiral.
- For $a = 0$, we get a semi-stable center.
- For $a \gt 0$, we get an unstable spiral.

From the above results, you can draw the solution curves.

We can also explicitly solve for the system and arrive at:

$$x(t) =  e^{a t}(c_1 \cos t + c_2 \sin t) \\ ~~~y(t) = e^{at}(-c_1 \sin t + c_2 \cos t)$$

Of course, using that closed-form solution, you can do a parametric plot of the solutions.

Here is an animated phase portrait for varying $a \in [-11, 11]$ in steps of $1$:

[image]

Comment: Colorful! Animated! So cool!